# Find orientation of a vector perpendicular to two lines

Tags: vectors

Given two lines:

$$r_1(t) = (a_1, b_1, c_1) + t(p_1, q_1, r_1)$$

$$r_2(s) = (a_2, b_2, c_2) + s(p_2, q_2, r_2)$$

To find the orientation of a vector perpendicular to these two lines, I believe I need a cross product. So I need a vector from both lines. If I set t = 0 and s = 0, does this work? e.g.

let $t = 0, s = 0$

$v_1 = (a_1, b_1, c_1)$
$v_2 = (a_2, b_2, c_2)$

$v_1 \times v_2 = v_3$

$v_3$ is perpendicular to $r_1(t)$ and $r_2(s)$?

Also since it is asking for the orientation of this vector, do I have to do anything to $v3$ or is it already an orientation?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Take the cross product of the direction vectors $(p_1,q_1,r_1)$ and $(p_2,q_2,r_2)$

Comment: What do I do with 's' and 't'? @J.W.Tanner

Comment: $(a1, b1, c1)$ is a point on the first line, and $(p1, q1, r1)$ is a direction vector. $t$ is the parameter of a point moving on the line. You only need the direction vector here. If you prefer, take the vector $r(1)-r(0)$. It's exactly $(p1, q1, r1)$.